# ¿Por qué mi sesión de usuario de otra pestaña, se actualiza a la nueva sesión después de recargar la pagina web, y no se mantiene?

Tags: php, mysqli, session

tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una login dinamico para 2 tablas en php y mysql, una se llama comprador y otra altaproveedor, con ese login deseo que detecte automáticamente si el usuario y la contraseña introducida en el formulario pertenecen a la tabla comprador, o a la tabla altaproveedor y me cree sus respectivas sesiones, dependiendo a que tabla pertenezca, el problema es que al loguearme como comprador accedo correctamente e incluso asta imprimo la variable de sesión con mi nombre de comprador (Daniel), pero si abro otra ventana en el navegador, y me logueo con otra cuenta de comprador (María), accedo y me muestra correctamente mis datos, pero en la ventana anterior del navegador, al recargar la pagina me doy cuenta que el nombre de usuario cambia y no se mantiene (de Daniel cambia a María, cuando debería seguir siendo Daniel al recargar y lo mismo me pasa con el el login de altaproveedor), sospecho que mi problema esta en el login al crear las sesiones... que estoy haciendo mal? gracias por la ayuda, este es mi codigo:

```
/* codigo de formulario.php */

<form action="validalogin.php" method="POST" class="for">
<label for="myfile">Usuario</label><br>
<input type="text" id="rfc" name="rfc" placeholder="Usuario"><br>

<label for="contraseña">Contraseña</label><br>
<input type="password" id="contraseña" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña"><br>
<a href="#">Restablecer</a>
<input type="submit" value="Acceder">
</form>


/*codigo de login.php*/

<?php
$rfc=$_POST['rfc'];
$usuario=$_POST['rfc'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];
SESSION_START();

require("../conexion/conexion.php");

$consulta="SELECT*FROM altaproveedor WHERE rfc = '$rfc' AND contraseña='$contraseña' ";
$resultado=mysqli_query($con,$consulta);


$consulta2="SELECT*FROM comprador WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contraseña='$contraseña' ";
$resultado2=mysqli_query($con,$consulta2);


$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
$filas2=mysqli_num_rows($resultado2);

if($filas){
    $_SESSION['username']=$rfc;
    header("Location:proveedor.php");
    exit();
}else if($filas2){
    $_SESSION['user']=$usuario;
    header("Location:compras.php");
exit();   
}

else{
    ?>
    <?php
    include("login.php");
    ?>
    <script>
    alert("Error en la autentificacíon");
    </script>
   <?php

}

?>
```

-- este es el documento al que me redirije despues de validar el login con php y mysql

```
<?php 
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
require("header.php");
require("../conexion/conexion.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css?">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">

    <title>Comprador</title>
</head>


<body>
<?php

echo "<h1>Bienvenido: $user</h1>";
?>
.....
```

este es un ejemplo de lo que ocurre fisicamente:

[image: Usuario logueado con el nombre de Daniel]

después al abrir otra ventana y logueamer con otra cuenta en el mismo loguin.[image: Otro usuario Maria]

y ahora en el usuario anterior si doy refrescar me cambia al usuario logueado recientemente, paso de Daniel a María, y deberia seguir siendo daniel aunque refresque la pagina. [image: Ahora de daniel a pasado a María, y debería seguir siendo Daniel]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Estás guardando con el mismo nombre de variable de session, si quieres poder tener dos loqueos en dos sistemas diferentes debes usar nombres de session diferentes.

Comment: No puedes tener varias sesiones abiertas en un mismo navegador, no importa si son pestañas independientes. Usa un navegador (o equipo) diferente para cada sesión.

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, tenias razón, se soluciona usando un navegador diferente. gracias a todos.